# Grails Build Test Data plugin having AST issues with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, ggts

I didn't have this problem before but now it just appeared and I don't know how to fix it. I tried it on many different Eclipse versions but I get the same problem.

> Groovy:Unable to run AST transform
>   grails.buildtestdata.mixin.BuildTransformation: missing class
>   grails/buildtestdata/mixin/BuildTestDataUnitTestMixin: are you
>   attempting to use groovy classes in an AST transform in the same
>   project in which it is defined?
>   http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin+2.0.0+FAQ#EclipsePlugin2.0.0FAQ-Q.DoesitsupportcustomASTtransformations%3F

Answer (score 0):

Could appear after a `grails clean`.

Run `Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies` and after that `Project -> Clean...`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your groovy version is correct for your version of Grails. I had the same issue while compiling a file with groovy 2.3 and then when the compiler got upgraded to 2.4 the @Build annotation failed, the AST transform did not work properly.